# no calendar display for date picker

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Can i get help on datepicker functionality that i have tried by following the steps i got from internet using MVC4. The problem is that the calender does not display in a date textbox for user to choose a date but all refencing and JQuery codes are entered.

Here is my code on my model:

```
{public class Movies
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime releasedat { get; set; }
        public string genre { get; set; }
        public decimal price { get; set; }
    }}
```

Here is the code for my controllers:

```
{public class JqueryController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Jquery/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }}
```

Here is my code on top of a view to reference a datepicker script:

```
{@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
<script >
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>

<h2>Date Time Picker</h2>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>}
```

I had also reference on my Start_App folder the relevant bundles, Here is my code:

{bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css",
                "~/Content/jquery-ui.css"));}
```

Also on my Layout I did add the JQuery script references, Her is my code:

```
 { @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")}
```

--------------------------------Thanks--------------------------------------------------

Comment: any console errors????

Comment: There are no console errors because the application still executes normal. There are no effect after all.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using? Because not all browsers support the date picker functionality.